# Converting from nested <c:forEach> to <display:table>

Tags: jsp, displaytag

I have the code below that I want to convert to <`display:table>`, but I am not sure how to display the content of the second `<c:/forEach>`. 
Basically, my table displays students and enrolments related to them. Each student contains a list of enrolments. Each pair one one student and one enrolment should be displayed in a new line.

I tried a few things, but the results were not what I expected. Any ideas would be appreciated.

my original code:

```
<c:forEach var="student" items="${students}">
                        <c:if test="${not empty student.enrolments}">
                            <c:forEach var="enrolment" items="${student.enrolments}">
                                <tr class="even_row">

                                    <td class="detail_l">${student.familyName}</td>
                                    <td class="detail_l">${student.firstName}</td>
                                    <td class="detail_l"><fmt:formatDate
                                        value="${student.dateOfBirth}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" /></td>
                                    <td class="detail_l">${student.sexCode}</td>
                                    <td class="detail_l">
                                    <a href="javascript:goToMenuOption('sisStudentUnits');">${student.studentNo}</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="detail_l">${enrolment.courseNo}</td>
                                    <td class="detail_l">${enrolment.enrolmentInstitution.instNo}</td>
                                    <td class="detail_l">${enrolment.firstEnrolmentYear}</td>
                                    <td class="detail_l">${enrolment.studentEnrolmentCode}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </c:if>
                    </c:forEach>
```

My conversion, that is not working (the ones that start with enrolment will cause errors on the jsp file. E.g.: Error looking up property "enrolment.courseNo"):

```
<display:table name="students">
                <display:column property="familyName" title="Surname" />
                       <display:column property="firstName" title="First Name" />
                       <display:column property="dateOfBirth" title="Date of Birth" />
                       <display:column property="sexCode" title="Sex" />
                       <display:column property="studentNo" title="Student Number" />
                       <display:column property="enrolment.courseNo" title="Course No (V/A)" />
                       <display:column property="enrolment.enrolmentInstitution.instNo" title="College/Centre"/>
                       <!display:column property="enrolment.firstEnrolmentYear" title="Year"/>
                       <!display:column property="enrolment.studentEnrolmentCode" title="Enr. Status"/>                  
                </display:table>
```

Thank you in advance,

Thais.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: See bottom of this answer for updated answer ...**

From the forEach example we can see that the forEach is looping on:

${student.enrolments}  (plural)

and is dynamically creating a variable called "enrolment" (singular) as a temporary variable to access the properties of the current row.

However the display:column example's property attributes are referencing "enrolment" (singular) which doesn't exist.

You probably want to create a table within a table here (i.e. a nested table).   See this example, and make sure to check out the "View source" button in the upper right to understand how the nested tables work:

http://demo.displaytag.org/displaytag-examples-1.1/example-nestedtables.jsp

---

In continuation .... based on wanting a flat list containing a sublist, then I believe you will need to do something like this:

```
<display:table name="students" id="student">
   <c:forEach items="${student.enrolments}" var="enrolment">
        <display:column property="familyName" title="Surname" />
        <display:column property="firstName" title="First Name" />
        <display:column property="dateOfBirth" title="Date of Birth" />
        <display:column property="sexCode" title="Sex" />
        <display:column property="studentNo" title="Student Number" />
        <display:column title="Course No (V/A)">
            ${enrolment.courseNo}
        </display:column>
        <display:column title="College/Centre">
            ${enrolment.enrolmentInstitution.instNo}
        </display:column>
       ...
   </c:forEach>
</display:table>
```

Comment: Thanks Alfreema, but the system layout is to display one pair per line, not a table inside other table. with the nested <c:foreach> I was being able to do that, but with the <display:table> I am not being able to.

Comment: Not sure if it notifies you that I have edited the original answer.   That should give you a flat layout like the nested forEach.

Comment: Hi Alfreema, I tried that as well. I wouldn't say it ignores the for each, but it won't create new rows. at the end, it will append the different courses (so, for 3 enrolments related to one student, it will display three columns named "course no" in the same row.
At the end I created a abject that each student has one enrolment, so, for instance, instead of one student object containing 3 enrolments, I have 3 students with one enrolment each. Maybe that is not a brilliant solution, but I had to move to other tasks.